# How to return other type of collection to gridView selected items

Tags: c#, list, collections, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a Windows Store app with c#.

I have a `GridView` in my app. the gridview's sources is my class list. I created a class for Collection List<>.

in the template of `GridView`, textboxes and imagebox are exist. when the user select an item in `GridView`, I want to return value type of my class .

For example the user selects first item, gridview will give me a collection list of my class.

How I can do it?

Comment: Please elaborate little bit more. "in the template of gridview, textboxes and imagebox are exist. when the user select an item in gridview, i want to return value type of my class . For example the user selects first item, gridview will give me a colloction list of my class." its little confusing?????

Comment: okay. I have a music class. and I have a Collection of music. use like that List<music>.

And program scans user's music library and add music in List<Music> variable. 

After the scan, add all List<Music> items to Gridview's ItemsSource.

The user will see own music in the gridview and select musics in GridView.

After the selection, when user click the play button, the selected items add the another List<Music> variable. 

Can I explain more?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex!=-1)
   return datagridview.Rows[datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as T // where T is denoted in Collection List<T>.
```

Comment: Where will I use this code? in the event of selecteditemschanged or what?

Comment: Use it where you want to get the object associated to the current row. Where do you feel you need it? Where do you go to process that object?

Comment: when user click the button, the selected items will be assigned to List<myclass>. how can I use that?